# Gnome theme showing very small menues

Tags: gnome, nautilus, themes, gtk

I had the awesome [Adapta](https://github.com/adapta-project/adapta-gtk-theme/) theme installed on my system. Then I ran [this](https://github.com/tliron/install-gnome-themes) script to install more themes. I'm not sure what change it did, but since then Adapta theme is giving Nautilus sidebar and context menu a look like this:
[image]

Whereas it should have normal spacing like this:
[image]

And here is the context menu:
[image]

I've tried install Adapta from latest master from source, from a point in past I've known it to work but it just doesn't work. I'm sure its not a bug with Adapta's code as a few other themes too have started showing this behavior.

What has gone with wrong with my system and how can I do to fix this and get themes to work correctly on my system?

System information:
GNOME 3.18 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You should file a bug report with the maintainer of the theme. I highly advise you not run scripts to install themes as themes are kept in `~/.themes` and all you need to do is download the archive and extract it to `~/.themes`. I looked at the script and although it is well written it does a lot more then downloading and extracting themes.

Answer (score 1):

According to the description of [the script you linked](https://github.com/tliron/install-gnome-themes), it installs themes into `~/.themes` directory. So removing this directory should undo the aforementioned script's action.

After removing the `~/.themes` directory, purge Adapta theme from your system. 
Then reinstall it from [their PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Etista/+archive/ubuntu/adapta) by running

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tista/adapta
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install adapta-gtk-theme
```

Comment: Good suggestion, however, if you look at the script it does a lot more than placing themes in `~/.themes`. Purging and reinstalling a package will affect system files, outside $HOME, but will NOT AFFECT settings in the users `~/.themes` so in this case I would not expect reinstalling to help, but it may.

Comment: Removing ~/.themes directory and re-installing the theme fixed it. Thank you.